# Add values from two selectbox

Tags: javascript

I have a question. For example, a bus ticket price. If it goes from

- `A` to `B`, the price is `300`
- `B` to `C` = `400`
- `C` to `D` = `200`
- `D` to `A` = `600`

It goes one way (`A` to `B` to `C` to `D` to `A` and so on), and it is stored in two select boxes.

So, `1st` select box is for **source** and the `2nd` is for **destination**.

If I choose `A` for first select box and `C` for second, it should charge me `700` (`300 + 400`). If I go from `D` to `C`, it should charge me `1300` (`600 + 300 + 400`). How to write that in Javascript ? It seems simple but it confuses me.

Here is the sample code, but it just add values from two select boxes. What I wanted is add values that has one way flow. For example if I go from `D` to `B`, the result should be `900`. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
p{
    display: inline;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>From :</p>
<select name= "from">
   <option value="2000">A</option>
   <option value="5000">B</option>
   <option value="3000">C</option>
   <option value="10000">D</option>
</select>
<p>To :</p>
<select name= "to">
   <option value="2000">A</option>
   <option value="5000">B</option>
   <option value="3000">C</option>
   <option value="10000">D</option>
</select>
<button type="button" onclick="output();">Calculate</button><br>
<p id="result"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
var result = document.getElementById('result');
function output(){
    var sour = document.getElementsByName("from")[0].value;
    var dest = document.getElementsByName("to")[0].value;
    var price = 0;
    var x;
    for (x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
        if (sour[x] != dest[x]){
            price += parseInt(sour) + parseInt(dest);
            result.innerHTML = price;
            console.log (price);
        }

    }
} 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you want people to help you you will need to provide some sample code.  See this for more information - http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What libraries can you use (jQuery, angular)? Like @JohnC said, please tell us how you tried to solve the problem until now.

Comment: sorry. I'm new at here. I already posted the codes

Comment: Would you be open to using jQuery?

Comment: jQuery is still new for me. I can consider it if it can't be executed with javascript only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always a good idea to keep your data and your representation seperated (there are complete frameworks built around that).

In your case the seperation of data would be taking the price from the `<option value="val">` to the javascript as a data object holding the price values for different areas.

Then you could scan through this data object and create your sum

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Aides/ys8et1h2/) for a possible implementation.

---

*Feel free to ask in the comments if anything is unclear*

Comment: Yeah, thanks for your help ! I will try to learn more about this JS. But why when I choose D for source and A for destination, it returns 20000 as result. Shouldn't it be 12000 ? I want a one way flow so it can't go back from D to C to B to A

Comment: And oh yeah. Maybe my explaination is unclear. What I wanted is when A as source and B as destination the result should be 2000. And when A as source and C as destination the result should be 7000. (2000 + 5000) P.S : A > 2000, B > 5000, C > 3000, D > 10000

Comment: you have the indices of both entries. what I did in my example is looping from lower value to higher value, so you could travel in both directions.

If you want to go one direction only with D connecting to A you could check if `destIndex < sourIndex` and then sum from 0 to destIndex and from sourIndex to maxIndex.

After seeing your comment - just exclude the destination index respectively

Comment: Ermm. Sorry for bothering you. I still don't get it. Can you show me how ? And also thanks so much for your help ^^

Comment: Check out [this update](https://jsfiddle.net/Aides/ys8et1h2/1/) and see if you can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest solution I can think of is setting the label/value pairs in an array and working on that:

```
var arr = [{
  label: 'A',
  val: 2000
}, {
  label: 'B',
  val: 5000
}, {
  label: 'C',
  val: 3000
}, {
  label: 'D',
  val: 10000
}, ];


function output() {
  var sour = document.getElementsByName("from")[0].value;
  var dest = document.getElementsByName("to")[0].value;

  var res = arr.reduce(function(ac, x) {
      //first you filter the objects in between sout and dest
      if (x.label.charCodeAt() >= sour.charCodeAt() && x.label.charCodeAt() <= dest.charCodeAt())
      return ac += x.val;
      //else
      return ac;
    }, 0)
  result.innerHTML = res;
  console.log("res", res)

}
```

this procedure relies on array.reduce, if you're new to JS this is a really important method for working with arrays.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maio/7g9y2s8o/2/)

Comment: Thanks for your help ! But it returned 0 when D to A. What i wanted is when D to B the result is 600 + 300 = 900

Answer (score 0):

@Aides answer is right but it uses some JS magic, which might not be the best thing when trying to understand the code.

Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gxxpjy6j/

The code uses a graph like data structure, but it can be easily adjusted to use a full blown graph. Also the code is really easy to understand.

**HTML**:

```
<body>
<p>From :</p>
<select name= "from">
   <option value="A">A</option>
   <option value="B">B</option>
   <option value="C">C</option>
   <option value="D">D</option>
</select>
<p>To :</p>
<select name= "to">
   <option value="A">A</option>
   <option value="B">B</option>
   <option value="C">C</option>
   <option value="D">D</option>
</select>
<button type="button" onclick="output();">Calculate</button><br>
<p id="result"></p>
</body>
```

**Javascript**

```
var result = document.getElementById('result');
output = function output(){
    var src = document.getElementsByName("from")[0].value;
    var dst = document.getElementsByName("to")[0].value;
    var curr = src;
    var price = 0;
    var x;

    var adjList = {
        'A': ['B', 2000],
      'B': ['C', 5000],
      'C': ['D', 3000],
      'D': ['A', 10000],
    }

    while (curr != dst) {
        price += adjList[curr][1];
      curr = adjList[curr][0];
    }

    result.innerHTML = price;
}
```

Hope this helps, even if not the selected answer.

Comment: yeah, Thanks ! I will learn it also. I'm still new at this, so pardon me.